# calling python method from c++ "library"

Tags: c++, python, extending

Through a code written in C++ code that embeds python call external python class and execute a method of the class (**FileHandler**). That works.
I generate a library of that code in C++ (libSome.so) for use in python with c_types and making a wrapper to try to run the above method gives segmentation fault. Any ideas?

(C++)This is the embedded code then generated as a shared library (libSome.so):

```
...
    /* Funcion de python */
        setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);

        Py_Initialize();

        PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("filehandler");
        assert(module != NULL);

        PyObject* class = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "FileHandler");
        assert(class != NULL);

        PyObject* inst = PyInstance_New(class, NULL, NULL);
        assert(inst != NULL);
        result = PyObject_CallMethod(inst, (char*)"write", (char*)"(iiii)",ori,serv, id, timeStamp);
        assert(result != NULL);
        Py_Finalize();
```

(Python) Code used by the library

```
import os

class FileHandler:
     def __init__(self):
          self.workingDirectory = os.getcwd()
          pass

     def write(self, NodoOrigen, Servicio, Id, payload):
          try:
           os.mkdir(str(NodoOrigen))
          except:
           pass

      os.chdir(str(NodoOrigen)+"/")
      try:
           os.mkdir(str(Servicio))
      except:
           pass

      os.chdir(self.workingDirectory)
      os.chdir(str(NodoOrigen)+"/"+str(Servicio)+"/")
      try:
           f = open(str(Id),"a")        
      except:
           print "No se puede abrir el archivo"
      f.write(str(payload))
      f.close()
      os.chdir(self.workingDirectory)
```

Comment: Serious lack of code and details.

Comment: 63rd line has a bug on the left. needs to be `buf-1` instead of `buf`

Comment: Why line of code segfaults? I'm also confused by the reference to ctypes. If you want to embed C++ code in Python use an extension. Would be weird to use ctypes to load this code which then simply calls back into Python. Not even sure if that works.

Comment: Hmm.. are you by any chance calling this c++ code from inside python, eg, through the `ctypes` library?

Comment: It's amazing that you have edited the question and still refuse to tell us which line of code results in segfault. You probably don't know. Which means you need to back up and do some debugging.

Comment: David I edit the line that gives no segmentation fault. Sorry for my English, maybe can not express my question to you can understand it.
I solved my problem by returning a value to the python code instead of instantiating an object python from C + +. Yet it was not the way I wanted. Perhaps the answer of "benpmorgan" would have been correct.
Thank you very much to all and sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your issue as there isn't really enough information here, but ctypes is only meant to call C functions; to call C++ functions, you need to wrap your C++ functions with a function in an `extern "C"` block.

For an example of this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/145649/121714

Comment: python -> c + +. Works (wrapper)
c + + -> python with shared library does not work.
The problem is when from the library (c + +) I want to call a python class method from the generated shared library.
Apologies, my English is not very good at explaining the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your use of `PyInstance_New`: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-March/195516.html

Maybe try this instead:

```
PyObject* inst = PyObject_CallObject(class, NULL);
```

and make FileHandler inherit from object in your Python code.

```
class FileHandler(object):
    ...
```

Is this your actual code though? If it is C++, it shouldn't be letting you use a variable called `class`, and `assert(instance != NULL);` should read `assert(inst != NULL);`

Also, which line is actually causing the segfault?

Another possibility: if you are starting this from Python, then calling C++ which calls Python, the C++ code shouldn't call `Py_Initialize();` or `Py_Finalize();` (however, if you have a C++ application embedding Python, that would be fine)